# Socket.IO Without Port Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Do i have to use port number to run socket.io or is it possible to access a socket.io in client side without a port number?

```
https://mydomain.com/chat2.html

NOT https://mydomain.com:3000/chat2.html
```

i read somewhere to use Nginx but not sure how to implement it, in nodejs! or can i use .htaccess for mirroring domain?

Comment: you have to setup your node server to port 80

Comment: @jack.the.ripper - this is https, so the default is 443, not 80.

Comment: Yep sorry my bad not 80 but 443, but the idea keeps the same

Answer (score 1):

For `http`, if no port number is specified, then the browser defaults to port 80.

For `https`, if no port number is specified, then the browser defaults to port 443.

So, if you want to use an https URL without a port number, then your server needs to be listening on port 443 because that is the default port number that the browser will use when no port number is specified in an https URL.